# How to decide shape of a n-dimension array in numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, n-dimensional

How can i say shape of a n-dimension matrix in numpy 
for example

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([[[1,2],[3,4]]])
print(a.shape)
```

output of these is (1,2,2)
How can i say it without using a computer.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your questions

Comment: Sorry i did 'nt mean it. But due to bad reputations i removed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 opening brackets at the beginning, so the shape has 3 elements.

The first shape element is 1, because the first opening bracket contains one element, ie. "[[1,2],[3,4]]".

The second shape element is 2, because you have two elements on that level, "[1,2]" and "[3,4]".

The third shape element is 2, because again you have two elements on that level "1" and "2" (as well as "3" and "4").